# Is multiplication by bounded, continuous functions bounded on $BMO$?

Tags: harmonic-analysis

I first asked this [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1884569/is-multiplication-by-bounded-continuous-functions-bounded-on-bmo) to no response.

I know that if $f\in L^\infty$ then the multiplication operator $\varphi\mapsto\varphi f$ is not bounded on $BMO$, see eg. [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/611201/a-bound-for-the-product-of-two-functions-in-bmo). The obvious counterexample is something like $f=1_{x\geq0}$ and $\varphi=\log|x|$, since the $BMO$ness of $\log|x|$ relies on the function diverging at zero from the left and right. But what happens if we assume $f$ is also continuous to rule out counterexamples like this one? Can we now say $\|\varphi f\|_{BMO}\leq\|\varphi\|_{BMO}\|f\|_{L^\infty}$?

**Edit:** It was pointed out in the comments that this claim is false, but might be true of "continuous" is replaced with "Lipschitz."

Comment: I doubt your final inequality is true, since one could take $f$ to be a continuous approximation to the Heavisde step function. This also leads me to suspect the answer to your stated question is false, by some kind of sliding-hump argument, but I confess I have not thought this through properly

Comment: @YemonChoi You might be right. Maybe we have boundedness if $f$ is Lipschitz instead?

Comment: Stan: Lipschitz sounds more plausible to me, but that's just a guess on my part. Pointwise multipliers of BMO are going to be pointwise multiplies of real $H^1$, by the duality that @ChristianRemling mentions, and that might be a way to confirm or refute the Lipschitz claim

Comment: The function $1$ has vanishing BMO norm, but the function $\varphi 1$ usually does not, so boundedness fails.  By using suitable truncations one can still obtain unboundedness even if one restricts to compactly supported functions.